# Ejabberd 17: How to create a hook which is called for offline messages?

Tags: ejabberd, ejabberd-module, ejabberd-api, ejabberd-hooks

I want to create a hook which is called whenever an offline message is created. Example: user-a(online) send a message to user-b(offline). Then as per ejabberd the message is stored and sent when user-b comes online. But in this situation, I want to call a local server POST URL with the data. How to create such a hook?

This hook is created so that I can from the local server send a push notification. Thus whenever a user comes online he/she will get the offline message as the push notification.

There is no step by step implementation for this. If anyone knows this it will be of great help.

Answer (score 1):

There are two hooks called when a message is sent to a local account that is offline: ejabberd_sm calls offline_message_hook. And mod_offline calls store_offline_message. Search for that in the ejabberd source code, and you will find example code to use them.

Answer (score 1):

Building on [Badlop's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50874018/1703291), I have created a [module](https://github.com/processone/ejabberd-contrib/tree/master/mod_push_offline) that does exactly what you need to achieve from an offline_hook. Only with a difference that you'll have to connect a [component](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0114.html) to ejabberd instead of getting messages on REST API.